# Resetting the color profile

Tags: windows-xp, display, display-settings

I've got an annoying problem.  I have a game that I have adjusted the brightness and contrast settings within it to make it much more playable.

Unfortunately, the game is a bit unstable and if it crashes it doesn't put the monitors back where they are supposed to be.  Rebooting of course fixes it but that's annoying.  I can't find anything in the display properties that is remotely relevant.

How do I get the setting back to default?

(XP Pro SP3, Nvidia cards.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried running the game again and exiting it immediately, before it's had a chance to crash?

Comment: That doesn't work.  When it exits normally it resets things to how they were before it ran, not to the bootup state.

Comment: You can use a freeware tool like [RivaTuner](http://www.guru3d.com/index.php?page=rivatuner) or [nHancer](http://www.nhancer.com/) to create display settings profiles.  Create a base profile for your normal settings and use that when this problem occurs.  I believe you can set up auto-profiles for games as well, although that typically involves changing settings on launching rather than exiting a game.  Still, worth exploring I think.

Comment: It finally crashed.  I installed RivaTuner and created a default profile but I find I don't even need it-- the mere act of calling up the screen to set the low level profile resets the monitor to what it should be.  Unfortunately I have no way of accepting a comment as the right answer but since I see you also made the original post I'll accept it anyway.